# unable to Deserialize a wcf Class object

Tags: .net, json, winforms, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF service with WSHttpBinding. Both Client and server are on .net Platform. On windows form application I am calling a function to get the task and save that task in a file, later on, load that task as:

```
DataContract()>
Public Class Task

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property UID As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Name As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property progress As String 

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Type As Long
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Version As String  Version

    <DataMember()>
        Public Property Status As Long
    <DataMember()>
        Public Property Narr As String
    <DataMember()>
        Public Property Dt As Date
End Class
```

I am calling a function that serializes the object and saves to file so that later on, that can easily be loaded to object as:

```
Function GetSaveTask()
   Dim Task_ As serv.Task = ServObj.GetTask() '' Calling Service to get Task
   Dim ObStrng As String = Jserialize(Task_)
   File.WriteAllText("D:\Task.ini", ObStrng)
End Function
Function LoadTask()
   Dim Task_ As serv.Task
   Dim ObStrng As String = File.ReadAllText("D:\Task.ini")
   Task_ = Deserialize(Of serv.Task)(ObStrng)

End Function
Public Shared Function Jserialize(Of T)(ByVal obb As Object) As Object
    Dim serializer As New Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Return serializer.Serialize(obb)
End Function
 Public Function Deserialize(Of T)(ByVal obb As String) As Object
    Dim JavaScriptSerializer As New Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Return JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(Of T)(obb)
End Function
```

Serialized Data in Task.ini :

```
[{"ExtensionData":{},"Dt":"\/Date(1490985000000)\/","Name":"Task-2017",
"Narr":null,"Status":20,"Type":0,"UID":"ABBB-KKKK","Version":"1.0.1.2","progress":20}]
```

I can only use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`.
The Task_ can easily serialize and saved to File. But LoadTask() is unable to Deserialize and throwing an error :

> No parameterless constructor defined for the type of 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject'

I have tried to create a proxy class same as Class *Task*, and save it to file. But the service keeps on updating the DataMember. We just update the service reference and everything works fine. So the proxy class will be an overhead and have to keep on updating as service class changes (which is not possible throughout the project).

Why is it unable to deserialize? Is there any way to load all, except ExtensionData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtensionData is causing that error. The ExtensionData is actually a feature that must be built into the type to enable round-tripping. It is always emitted by the DataContractSerializer. As you said, service keeps on updating, one thing you can do is, every time updating the service reference, comment the ExtensionData and its implementation.

```
 <System.NonSerializedAttribute()>  _
 Private extensionDataField As System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
```

and remove `Implements` :

```
Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
```